# Migrating Struts1 <logic:iterate> tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I am in process to migrate some Struts1 code to Struts2 and confused about migration of below tags.

**Struts1:**

```
<logic: notEmpty name="newsListForm" property="generalNews.list">
    <logic:iterate id="generalNews"
        name="newsListForm"
        property="generalNews.list"
        type="com.ab.NewsDTO"
        indexId="rowCount">
        <%
            if(rowCount.longValue() % 2 == 0){
             bgcolor = "#FFFFF";
            }else{
             bgcolor = "#EEEEE";
            }
        %>
     </logic: iterate>
    </logic: notEmpty>
```

I have migrated above code as:

**Struts2**

```
<s:if test="(newsListBean.generalNews.list != null)">
 <s:iterator id="generalNews"
            values="generalNews.list"
            status="incrementer">
    <s:if test="#incrementer.even==true">
<% pageContext.setAttribute("bgcolor","#FFFFFF")%>
</s:if>
 <s:else>
<% pageContext.setAttribute("bgcolor","#EEEEEE")%>
</s:else>
>
 
</s:iterator>
</s:if>
```

Is it a correct way to migrate these iterate & `<logic:notEmpty>` tags?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not correct. The original code use tags and scriptlet code to generate some text which is probably a JavaScript code.

But converted code doesn't do it. Instead it is used to set a page context attribute.

Comment: can you tell me the equivalent Struts2 code or some guidelines how it's done?

Comment: Thanks! What happens to DTO object given in "type" in S1 code. Don't we need it in S2?

Comment: @AbN It's not clear what you're asking; the type of the object is irrelevant.

Comment: @DaveNewton I meant "type" attribute of the <logic:iterate> tag from Struts1. I am aware that S2 <iterator> tag does not have type attribute but what happens to DTO class then?

Comment: @AbN What "happens" to it? Nothing. OGNL, like standard JSP EL, relies on JavaBean naming conventions. Type is irrelevant.

Comment: @AbN It&#39;s not an object but a class. If you iterate a collection the type is inferred from generics.

Comment: @RomanC If it is inferred from generics & DTO doesn't come into picture(that's what I understood from above discussion), why I am neither getting value in collection to be displayed nor getting any error?

Comment: I don't know do you have the value in collection or not. The collection could be empty. Did you check the collection data?

Comment: Collection has required data. Here problem is how to print it on jsp as collection which I am iterating is of type **CustomList** (generalNews) of **List** (list) of **Object** (com.ab.NewsDTO)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat off-topic, but related: there's a way, way cleaner way to do this by using proper CSS.

First have classes for the row colors: this is something you should have anyway rather than wedging presentation definitions into JSP code:

```
<style>
  .row-0 { bgcolor: #ffffff }
  .row-1 { bgcolor: #eeeeee }
</style>
```

Then use those to construct classnames for whatever it is you need (here, likely `<td>`s):

```
<s:iterator id="generalNews" values="generalNews.list" status="stat">
  <tr class="row-${stat.count % 2}">
    <!-- ... Table row content ... -->
  </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

*(Roughly; this is from memory.)*